# How to check programmatic by preprocessor directive whether a pre-compiled header is required in Visual C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, c-preprocessor, precompiled-headers

Sometimes it would be useful to know whether the compiler requires a pre-compiled header or not, and how the header file is called. My goal is to add some preprocessor directives like this:

```
#ifdef REQUIRES_PRECOMPILED_HEADER
#include PRECOMPILEDHEADER_FILE
#endif
```

So my question is: Are there predefined variables like `REQUIRES_PRECOMPILED_HEADER` and `PRECOMPILEDHEADER_FILE`?

Comment: If there is, it will be listed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay.aspx).

Comment: Are you sure that this is the complete list of predefined variables? If so the answer would be 'No'. But as far as I know Microsofts documentation is sometimes incomplete or out of date.

Comment: The answer is indeed no.  Convention is stdafx.h.  But create your own project, make it a static lib project.

Comment: -1 "Since Visual C++ requires the pre-compiled header to be included into all source files" is wrong

Comment: So correct me, but don't just say "is wrong". I just answer at my best knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well presumably your source files will not need any of the headers included in the precompiled header. So, if you are trying to include your source files in a project where other source files do use precompiled headers, just make sure precompiled headers are [turned off for yours](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1hy7a92h).

Just select the properties for your source files, and under "Precompiled Header" select "Not Using Precompiled Headers".

Comment: Okay that solves the problem in the easy way. (I usually avoid using pre-compiled headers, so I'm not really used to them. Thanks for that hint.)

Answer (score 1):

It's not your task to support others' use of precompiled headers. It's up to them to add your header to their precompiled header, or not. You just create trouble by trying to do it for them.

So, problem solved: don't do that.

It's unnecessary and it creates trouble.